# How to make an mstest project run another mstest project

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mstest

Running .net 4.5

I have a single solution with multiple projects.

Some projects depend on other projects. I'd like my mstest projects to sort of mirror this.

So I have project1 and a test project for project1. I have project2 and a test project for project2. Project1 depends on project2.

When I run the mstest project for project1 I want it to also invoke the mstest project for project2. Does mstest support this? Project1 has a reference configured for project2 can an mstest project have a reference to another mstest project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wildcard test containers to mstest. exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669122/wildcard-test-containers-to-mstest-exe)

Comment: No. I could have a command that runs both test projects- thats not what im asking. Im asking if its possible to be able to call one mstest test project and have that project automatically run another project (not having to do this manually myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MStest projects are simply dlls that are scanned by the mstest.exe for test methods. The project itself cannot call another project. A script that scans for dlls and then executes mstest against all of them is the only way I know to do what you are asking.