# Execute multiple .dll with MSTest using batch (bat)

Tags: batch-file, jenkins-pipeline, mstest

currently we are building up a Jenkins-Pipeline, while building it up we found out that we need a few bat-scripts. But now I don't know any further. We have a Folder with all our Unit-Tests (about 27 .dll's, in sum 1788 Tests).

Example Paths:

> ```
> D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\SculiWebServiceTest.UnitTests\SculiWebServiceTests.dll
> D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\ExternalServices.UnitTests\ExternalServicesTests.dll
> D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\ServiceBus.IntegrationTests\ServiceBus.IntegrationTests.dll
> ```

And we want to execute all .dll and define a Quality-Gate (this means all Tests need to be passed), the following works:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" "/testcontainer:D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\SculiWebServiceTest.UnitTests\SculiWebServiceTests.dll"
```

But if you add more /testcontainer, we get an error **"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."**

Already read this post, but it didn't helped me "[wildcard test containers to mstest. exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669122/wildcard-test-containers-to-mstest-exe)", anybody have a solution here?

Comment: With so many tests, you will run into command-line length limit the sooner or later. You could run a loop in a batch or powershell script to pass all DLLs, one by one, to MSTest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that this is a string-limitations issue, if you don't use the "", it will work.

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\SculiWebServiceTest.UnitTests\SculiWebServiceTests.dll /testcontainer:D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\ExternalServices.UnitTests\ExternalServicesTests.dll /testcontainer:D:\Jenkins\Pipeline\trunk\Binaries\Unittests\ServiceBus.IntegrationTests\ServiceBus.IntegrationTests.dll
```

If you are using batch be careful that you don't use an enter between the different testcontainers.